# Looking for sanitized Cisco IOS XR configurations

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-xr, ciscoconfparse

I'm looking for someone who can answer with a sanitized Cisco IOS XR text configurations.

These configurations will be used to test [`ciscoconfparse`](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse) config parsing, specifically to start working on [ciscoconfparse feature request #292](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/issues/292) (add IOS XR parsing intelligence)

I'm looking for the whole config. Passwords / snmp-communities / sensitive-ip info changed but not removed. Lab or prod FW configs are fine. Please indicate what firmware version the config is from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone responded privately with sanitized IOS XR configurations... they are on github here:

- [sample_05.iosxr](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/blob/main/tests/fixtures/configs/sample_05.iosxr)
- [sample_06.iosxr](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/blob/main/tests/fixtures/configs/sample_06.iosxr)
- [sample_07.iosxr](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/blob/main/tests/fixtures/configs/sample_07.iosxr)